Firebase Cloud Function triggers on create but raises "Resource string did not match expected format" Error
I'm deploying a Firebase Cloud Function using the Google-Github-Actions.
  - id: onItemCreate
    name: Deploy onItemCreate
    uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions@v1.0.1
    with:
      name: "onItemCreate"
      entry_point: "onItemCreate"
      runtime: ${{ env.RUNTIME }}
      region: ${{ env.GCP_REGION }}
      build_service_account: ${{ env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_BUILD }}
      service_account: ${{ env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_RUN }}
      event_trigger_type: "providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create"
      event_trigger_resource: "projects/my-project-id/databases/my-firestore-name/documents/items/{itemId}"
      event_trigger_service_account: ${{ env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_RUN }}

The cloud function correctly triggers whenever a document is created in /items. But always raises the same error. Example: I create a document (id: sfgQxqkDAcGXePoKcTQB) in /items and get the following error:
onItemCreatezd7hse2sjkl2 Error: Resource string did not match expected format: projects/my-project-id/databases/my-firestore-name/documents/items/sfgQxqkDAcGXePoKcTQB.
    at splitResource (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/middleware/background_event_to_cloud_event.js:104:19)
    at backgroundEventToCloudEventMiddleware (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/middleware/background_event_to_cloud_event.js:131:72)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:328:13)
    at /workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
    at next (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
    at legacyPubSubEventMiddleware (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/pubsub_middleware.js:72:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:328:13) 

I have no idea how to debug this because the cloud function does not even run because this error is raised before its invocation. I'm also confused because the resource does match the expected format and if it didn't, then why is the function even triggered?

Fixed it by using deploy-cloud-functions@main and adding more configuration.
- id: onItemCreate
  name: Deploy onItemCreate
  uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions@main
  with:
    name: "onItemCreate"
    entry_point: "onItemCreate"
    runtime: ${{ env.RUNTIME }}
    region: ${{ env.GCP_REGION }}
    build_service_account: ${{ env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_BUILD }}
    service_account: ${{ env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_RUN }}
    event_trigger_type: "google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.created"
    event_trigger_resource: "projects/my-project-id/databases/my-firestore-name/documents/items/{itemId}"
    event_trigger_filters: |-
      database=my-firestore-name
    event_trigger_service_account: ${{ env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_RUN }}

